# Expo: Standalone apk splash bug

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I made an standalone app using expo, the development phase is running as expected but when I run standalone, the splash screen is everywhere in the background,
Here are some screenshots...
[image: this is when i am running standalone app[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erWQe.jpg)

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I'm seeing the same thing in apk files

Comment: can you provide more details of your issue ?